# gcloud deploy not making dist folder

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, npm

Admittedly, I'm a novice at GCloud.  I "inherited" a project abandoned by the previous developer.  I'm trying to deploy a node app on the app engine.  The app won't start because it can't find the dist/server.js file.  That's because the entire dist folder is simply not there. I can look at previous versions and see the dist folder. Also, there's supposed to be a folder with a long string for a name that contains the manifest.json folder.  That's not there either.  I cloned the Github repository to a folder using the cloud shell.  Then I run npm install which gives me the node_modules directory.  Then I run npm build ./ (from within the folder that has the package.json).  Nada.  I've been fighting this for a day now and have gotten to the point where I'm just repeating myself.  Presumably this all worked before so if I can just figure out how to get those two folders I think I'll be golden.

Help!

Comment: I understand the dist folder should be created by the build script, so maybe share this info here. Also, if the GitHub repo is not private, would you consider sharing it here as well? This will help us understand better your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open up [Cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell#starting_a_new_session) and try the [following command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments#download_app):

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <project_id> -V <version> <output-dir>
```

It is part of a deprecated sdk, the standalone App Engine sdk, but it might take you out of this one. I've tested it with a python and a java app, both a few years old, and it has successfully downloaded both.

Good luck!